# How to flat/reshape a multidimentional dataframe by fixing a unique column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to [reshape](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking) a pandas dataframe. So, consider the following `df`:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   unique_id
Apple (Date 09/21/2016)     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     101
bannana (Date 09/30/2016)   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     102
cherry (New 04/05/2016)     tomatoes (New 04/07/2016)   potatoes (Date 11/08/2016)  pineapples (Date 04/11/2016)    carrots (Date 11/01/2016)   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     103
coconuts (Date 11/10/2016)  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     104
oranges (Date 11/01/2016)   watermelon (Date 11/07/2016)    pears (Date 11/08/2016)     carrots (Date 11/01/2016)   blackberry (New 01/22/2015)     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     105
kiwi (Date 11/09/2016)  carrots (Date 11/01/2016)   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     106
```

How can I set as an unique index the `unique_id` column in the following way? `(*)`:

```
    0                       unique_id
Apple (Date 09/21/2016)      101
bannana (Date 09/30/2016)    102
cherry (New 04/05/2016)      103
tomatoes (New 04/07/2016)    103
potatoes (Date 11/08/2016)   103
pineapples (Date 04/11/2016) 103
carrots (Date 11/01/2016)    103
NaN                          103    
NaN                          103
NaN                          103
NaN                          103
coconuts (Date 11/10/2016)   104      
NaN                          104
NaN                          104 
NaN                          104
NaN                          104
NaN                          104
NaN                          104
NaN                          104
NaN                          104
oranges (Date 11/01/2016)    105
watermelon (Date 11/07/2016) 105
pears (Date 11/08/2016)      105
carrots (Date 11/01/2016)    105
blackberry(New 01/22/2015)   105
NaN                          105
NaN                          105
NaN                          105
NaN                          105
kiwi (Date 11/09/2016)       106
carrots (Date 11/01/2016)    106
NaN                          106
NaN                          106
NaN                          106
NaN                          106
NaN                          106
NaN                          106
NaN                          106
```

For the above, I tried to use the [stack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [reset_index()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) methods in order to set as an index the `unique_id` column, in order to use it as "pivot":

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.stack().reset_index(drop=False))
df['col-index'] = df['unique_id']
df = df.set_index('col-index')
```

However, I guess I am complicating this task, thus how can I reindex the dataframe in order to get `(*)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If dont need rows with `NaN` values, use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('unique_id')
       .stack()
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .reset_index(name='a')

print (df)
    unique_id                             a
0         101       Apple (Date 09/21/2016)
1         102     bannana (Date 09/30/2016)
2         103       cherry (New 04/05/2016)
3         103     tomatoes (New 04/07/2016)
4         103    potatoes (Date 11/08/2016)
5         103  pineapples (Date 04/11/2016)
6         103     carrots (Date 11/01/2016)
7         104    coconuts (Date 11/10/2016)
8         105     oranges (Date 11/01/2016)
9         105  watermelon (Date 11/07/2016)
10        105       pears (Date 11/08/2016)
11        105     carrots (Date 11/01/2016)
12        105   blackberry (New 01/22/2015)
13        106        kiwi (Date 11/09/2016)
14        106     carrots (Date 11/01/2016)
```

If need `NaN` use:

```
df = df.set_index('unique_id')
       .stack(dropna=False)
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .reset_index(name='a')

print (df)
    unique_id                             a
0         101       Apple (Date 09/21/2016)
1         101                           NaN
2         101                           NaN
3         101                           NaN
4         101                           NaN
5         101                           NaN
6         101                           NaN
7         101                           NaN
8         101                           NaN
9         102     bannana (Date 09/30/2016)
10        102                           NaN
11        102                           NaN
12        102                           NaN
13        102                           NaN
14        102                           NaN
15        102                           NaN
16        102                           NaN
17        102                           NaN
18        103       cherry (New 04/05/2016)
19        103     tomatoes (New 04/07/2016)
20        103    potatoes (Date 11/08/2016)
21        103  pineapples (Date 04/11/2016)
22        103     carrots (Date 11/01/2016)
23        103                           NaN
24        103                           NaN
25        103                           NaN
26        103                           NaN
27        104    coconuts (Date 11/10/2016)
28        104                           NaN
29        104                           NaN
30        104                           NaN
31        104                           NaN
32        104                           NaN
33        104                           NaN
34        104                           NaN
35        104                           NaN
36        105     oranges (Date 11/01/2016)
37        105  watermelon (Date 11/07/2016)
38        105       pears (Date 11/08/2016)
39        105     carrots (Date 11/01/2016)
40        105   blackberry (New 01/22/2015)
41        105                           NaN
42        105                           NaN
43        105                           NaN
44        105                           NaN
45        106        kiwi (Date 11/09/2016)
46        106     carrots (Date 11/01/2016)
47        106                           NaN
48        106                           NaN
49        106                           NaN
50        106                           NaN
51        106                           NaN
52        106                           NaN
53        106                           NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, I am checking the solution, hold me on!

Comment: I'd stay away from Unique_id as a column name though, it doesnt look unique to me!

Comment: Similar, you can check it in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking).

Comment: Hey @jezrael, What about not fixing one?. Is that possible?, I tried: `f = df.set_index(['0_x', '1_x']).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='a')`. Nevertheless, I got: `Keyerror`

Comment: I think if use `set_index` with 2 columns you get obviously `MultiIndex` with 3 levels and if  `.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)` you remove only one level. maybe need add `.reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True)`, but the best is post new question with sample data and desired output.